# On SourceForge .Net, which page's url must I use as the web location from which my applications can check for updates automatically?

Tags: open-source, sourceforge

On SourceForge.net, which page's URL must I use as the web location from which my applications can check for updates automatically?

The Files page or the File Manager page?

Answer (score 4):

on the "files page" you can see a little feed-button (top right corner):

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8287/bild000.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8287/bild000.png)

i would use that feed.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, @akira. I will try it tonight. Have you used it before?

Comment: no, i know when we do a new release :)